# application evaluation window in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

who knows how to make such application evaluation windows in Flutter?
[image]

there are any ready decisions or through AlertDialog to do? It's just that the problem is that the AlertDialog has margins from the edges that cannot be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create this with the modal version of Flutter, which uses the **Dialog** class.
You can read more about it on [this example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html) on the Flutter Documentation

Here is a full example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [Dialog].

void main() => runApp(const DialogExampleApp());

class DialogExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DialogExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dialog Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DialogExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DialogExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DialogExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Text('This is a Title.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Text('This is a typical dialog.'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.star_border,
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Close'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog.fullscreen(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('This is a fullscreen dialog.'),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Close'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text('Show Fullscreen Dialog'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```